# Access 2010: unable to view hidden tables and ribbon tabs issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I've been working on an Access 2007 database in Access 2010. This was not written by me and I don't know the person who did write it so asking them is not an option.

The only tab I see is home and I cannot view hidden tables like MsysObjects. Is this some sort of read-only version? Are forms blocking what I want to see?

[image: What I'm currently looking at]

Comment: This question is really more appropriate to SuperUser, I am afraid. It is not exactly programming.

Comment: try opening database whilst holding down the shift button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the database whilst holding down the shift button.